# Finding which filesystem

Tags: filesystems, terminal

I have an external hard drive and would like to know what kind of a file system it has.

How do I find that out using the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
blkid -d /dev/VOLUME
/dev/VOLUME: UUID="97da23eb-542e-4f5f-9cc8-5108ee6a1f2e" TYPE="ext3"
```

But with external disks: Mind the difference between disks and partitions: `/dev/sdx` vs. `/dev/sdx1`. It may be useful to check with `fdisk -l /dev/sdx` or `cat /proc/partitions` first.